# How to fix sqlpackage failure to restore bacpac file to Linux, but not Windows

Tags: sql-server

I have a .bacpac file from an Azure SQL database and I'm trying to install it into SQL Server 2019 for Linux with this command:

```
sqlpackage /Action:Import /tsn:h-dev /tu:sa /tp:{sa password} /tdn:G_External /sf:G_External.bacpac
```

This creates this output:

```
Importing to database 'G_External' on server 'h-dev'.
Creating deployment plan
Initializing deployment
*** The source contains users that rely on an external authentication provider that is not supported by the target. These users will be treated as users without logins.
Time elapsed 00:00:24.07
*** An unexpected failure occurred: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I do the same into an installation of SQL Server 2019 on Windows 10, it works:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Import /tsn:DESKTOP-NM51MHA /tdn:G_External /sf:G_External.bacpac

Importing to database 'G_External' on server 'DESKTOP-NM51MHA'.
Creating deployment plan
Initializing deployment
*** The source contains users that rely on an external authentication provider that is not supported by the target. These users will be treated as users without logins.
Verifying deployment plan
Analyzing deployment plan
Importing package schema and data into database
Updating database
Importing data
Processing Import.
...
Successfully imported database.
Time elapsed 00:01:45.27
```

How do I fix this? Alternatively, how can I get further information from `sqlpackage` in order to diagnose what's wrong?

SQLServer versions:

Linux:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P {sa password} -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU1) (KB4527376) - 15.0.4003.23 (X64)
    Dec  6 2019 14:53:33
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) <X64>
```

Windows:

```
SQLCMD.EXE -S localhost -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)
        Sep 24 2019 13:48:23
        Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 18363: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: An NRE is always a code bug. Something produced a `null` but the code wasn't prepared to handle it. Perhaps, because `something` wasn't supposed to produce a null. [sqlpackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15) is a standalone tool though, which version are you using in each case? They may have fixed the bug in the latest version

Comment: That `something` can a system library though, From the exception's message it looks like `sqlpackage` is a .NET Core. .NET Core will use the system libraries for encoding conversions, timezones etc. Just guessing here, but what are the values of `LC_ALL` et al?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How do I determine the version of sqlpackage?

Comment: When did you install it? The latest [version is 18.4.2, released on December 13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/release-notes-sqlpackage?view=sql-server-ver15). Looking at the release notes it seems there was a fix for an NRE in 18.2.

Comment: On Linux, I installed yesterday from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2113331 The file is `sqlpackage-linux-x64-en-US-15.0.4630.1.zip`. That link came from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15 which claims that it's version `18.4.1`.

Comment: According to the linked notes, this should be the latest, which is bad. What are your locale settings? Perhaps it throws because it expected UTF8 ? There's a .NET Core deployment option that removes codepage support to reduce the binary size. WIthout it, code that tries to use a non-Unicode encoding throws, but the error is completely different

Comment: Oh, this is interesting. Following your link, I've downloaded the previous version (`18.4`. `15.0.4573.2`) and it works.

Comment: `locale -a` produces this list: `C
C.UTF-8
dutch
en_GB
en_GB.iso88591
en_GB.utf8
en_US.utf8
french
fr_FR
fr_FR.iso88591
fr_FR.utf8
nl_NL
nl_NL.iso88591
nl_NL.utf8
POSIX`

Answer (score 3):

As a work around, try different versions of sqlpackage.

The [Release notes for SqlPackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/release-notes-sqlpackage) page contains download links for previous versions of sqlpackage.

In my case, sqlpackage version 18.4 (build 15.0.4573.2) worked for me for this .bacpac file when version 18.4.1 (build 15.0.4630.1) did not.

Comment: Looks like a new bug then

Comment: I, too, was experiencing an issue using v18.4.1, but when I switched to v18.4, it worked just fine. In my case, it was throwing the exception when it was trying to recreate my database logins that were backed by external providers (i.e. Azure AD).

Comment: Maybe you'll know how to answer this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66444610/sqlpackage-import-maximum-db-size

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who may be encountering this vague error message when using sqlpackage, there is a `/Diagnostics` switch that will dump out A LOT of debug messages of exactly what sqlpackage is doing.

`/Diagnostics:true` -> print out the diagnostic information

`/Diagnostics:false` -> print out only result information (default)

Using this switch should help you determine exactly where in the backup file the error is occurring. This switch appears in at least as far back as v17.4.0, but possibly earlier. v17.4.0 is as far back as the current release history shows.