# SqlPackage import maximum db size

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlpackage, bacpac

I want to import a database from a `.bacpac` file to a SQL Server in Azure. I read the document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-import?view=sql-server-ver15

It says that there is a flag called `DatabaseMaximumSize=(INT32)`. I wanted to know if there's a limit that sqlpackage can support? For example if I got 8 gb of RAM available, will Sqlpackage be able to load larger `.bacpac`s than that, meaning it doesn't load it all to the memory?

Comment: I have never tried this.

Answer (score 0):

SQLPACKAGE.exe does not have to do anything with your system RAM.

Sqlpackage.exe will export and import much larger databases then your system ram.

When you import a bacpac file using sqlpackage.exe in Azure and you don't have target db created beforehand, then by default a db will be created in target server with max db size of 32gb only.

So if your db which you exported as bacpac was larger than 32gb then you should create your target db ( keep it empty) before importing bacpac file. Also, size of bacpac is not indicative of actual size of db, bacpac is highly compressed object and is nowhere related to actual db size.

Now coming to import parameter /p Database maximum size, I believe it is there to specify the maximum limit of your target db.